# WKWebView page goes under transparent status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to create an ios app that just loads my website which is mobile friendly. I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that when you scroll down the page some parts are shown below the status bar, which I preferably do not want. How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems that problem is in Constraint, Provide top constraint of your Webview with saferArea and constant should be 0.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: To define your Webviews position,width,height, what you used, constraint or something else?

Comment: I can see that you are using webview as rootView in loadView function `view = webView` don't do this add webView as a subView of rootView of your ViewController or decrese webView height which height is acuring by statusBar and navBar.

Comment: @Kazi Abdullah Al Mamun, I have the same problem. I tried to add webView as subview like this 'view.addSubview(webView)',  instead of `view = webView`, but there is only a white screen on the Simulator.  With  `view = webView`, all is ok, except the webView scrolls under the transparent status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for about an hour straight! Here's the solution, nice and simple (Xcode9).

1. Create a view (it will remain empty) and ensure that this new view is within your main view, you can drag it just underneath your navigation bar.
2. Remove any constraints you may have made previously. Drag the webview so that it is also within your main view and make sure that it is UNDERNEATH the new view you just created.
3. Select the new view and click on "Add New Constraints", top must be -20, left 0, right 0, do not add for bottom. Make the height 20 and click "Add Constraints".
   The NEGATIVE 20 for top is very important.
4. Select your webview and add constraints like this: top 0, left 0, right 0, bottom 0.

Your webview will now only start 20 points after the new view you created so it will never overlap.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController(here is Webview added) only use Autoresizing options(In viewController-view, the webview is add programmatically later in execution) in "Size Inspector" without use constraints:

[image]
[image]

And my code in viewcontroller of Webview is :

```
var webView2: UIWebView?
var hasConfiguredView = false
var screenSize = CGRect.zero
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    webView.frame.origin.x = 0
    webView.frame.origin.y = 0
    webView.frame.size.height = screenSize.height
    webView.frame.size.width = screenSize.width
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !hasConfiguredView {
        hasConfiguredView = true
        drawenormalwebview()
    }
}

private func drawenormalwebview(){

    let urlstring = "https://google.com"

    webView2 = UIWebView.init()

    webView2!.frame.origin.x = 0
    webView2!.frame.origin.y = 0.f
    webView2!.frame.size.height = screenSize.height
    webView2!.frame.size.width = screenSize.width

    webView2!.delegate = self

    webView2!.scrollView.bounces = false

    self.view.addSubview(webView2!)
    webView2!.isOpaque = false
    webView2!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    if let urls = URL(string: urlstring) {
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: urls,
                                   cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                                   timeoutInterval: 5.0)
        webView2!.loadRequest(myRequest)
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It almost works for me. The error I receive is: `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UIWebViewDelegate?'` Do you know what the problem is?